# VBScripting MSMQ COM Object on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, vbscript, com, msmq

My VBScript tries to load MSMQ COM Object to connect to a *remote* MSMQ server.

```
Set MSMQQueueInfo = CreateObject("MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo")
```

I enabled Messaging DCOM Proxy on my local computer

[image]

Script can't load COM object:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to also install "Message Queuing Server" even though I don't want to run MSMQ locally. Now the MSMQ COM object works.